# What collision-resistant algorithm for calculating hash sums allows you to add and subtract its terms, leading to a reproducible sum? (In any order)

Tags: security, math, vector, hash, hashmap

Excuse me for a stupid question, if this is possible to achieve by providing a high level of guarantees for the occurrence of collisions, and acceptable performance?

Comment: That would be not just a terrible property for a hash function to have, but is plain impossible given how hashing works, where we condense _blocks_ of data. So if you combined files, you'd have to put zero-bytes between the two to ensure they aligned to blocks, which would almost certainly break whatever should read this data, because it's guaranteed invalid now =)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a linear transformation, but I'm not sure. A linear transformation L has the property that L(x1, x2, ...) = L(x1) + L(x2) .... Perhaps you can provide more clarity on what properties you need this function to have. You need to provide more details before any sort of guarantees can be provided. For a hash function you can guarantee that there will be collisions just by invoking the pigeonhole princioke.

Comment: there is no standard cryptographic hash function that allows adding and subtracting hash sums while maintaining a reproducible sum. Hash functions are designed to be one-way functions, meaning they should be computationally infeasible to reverse or modify the output to obtain the original input or perform arithmetic operations directly on the hash values.